# Find a word containing special characters and delete them from the Input File file batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to search and find Emails containing for example @gmail.com and stock them to a new file "OUTPUT_FILE", and also delete the email from the "INPUT_FILE", I was able to do the first part (finding the email and stoking it to a new file).

But I couldn't delete it from the old one 'INPUT_FILE'

```batch-file
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion  EnableDelayedExpansion 
set INPUT_FILE=results.txt
set OUTPUT_FILE=emails.txt
set OUTPUT_FILE2=emails2.txt
set result=result.txt
set "REGEXP=[\.A-Z\-_][\.A-Z\-_]*@gmail.com"
>nul copy nul %OUTPUT_FILE%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%INPUT_FILE%) do for %%b in (%%a) do (
    for /f %%z in ('echo %%b ^| findstr /R /I "%REGEXP%"') do (
          echo %%z >> %OUTPUT_FILE%

           )

)
```

for example  INPUT_FILE

```
nour.elhouda.elarabi@gmail.com
houda@hotmail.com
nour@gmail.com
smile@outlook.com
sau@gmail.com
```

after runung the script i should have

INPUT_FILE

```
houda@hotmail.com
smile@outlook.com
```

OUTPUT_FILE

```
nalte.el@gmail.com
nour@gmail.com
sau@gmail.com
```

Comment: Hint: `< input.txt ( find "@gmail.com" > match.txt & find /V "@gmail.com" > nomatch.txt )` Just change `match.txt` by `output_file` and move `nomatch.txt` to `input_file`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response what does the  < input.txt  in the beginning do?

Comment: Thank you for your help you answer helped me this is the final code that worked for me!
**`@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion  EnableDelayedExpansion 
set INPUT_FILE=emails.txt 
set OUTPUT_FILE=results.txt
set OUTPUT_DELTE=result.txt
findstr "@gmail.com" %INPUT_FILE% > %OUTPUT_FILE% 
findstr /V "@gmail.com" %INPUT_FILE% > %OUTPUT_DELTE%`**